# Unable to build the mule maven project

Tags: maven, jboss, mule, mule-studio

I have created a mule maven project while running the project as : mule application with maven i am getting following error:

Failed to execute goal on project StandaloneTest: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mycompany:StandaloneTest:mule:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules:mule-module-xml:jar:3.4.0 in jboss (http://repository.jboss.com/)

I have following dependency generated by mule studio in my project pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-xml</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0-bighorn</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-xml</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

do we need com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules.mule-moudle-xml.jar also in order to have a xml module in our flow file since we already have a org.mule.modules.mule-module-xml.jar in our repository.

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate group id for mule-module-xml is org.mule.modules. Trying removing the second dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing both with this dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
  <artifactId>mule-module-xml</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The dependency is found in any of these 2 Maven repositories:

https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/groups/public/
https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/

Please let us know if that works. Thank you!